# Winforms TreeView with OwnerDrawText: "DrawDefault=true" partially obscures/paints over checkboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, ownerdrawn

I started playing with the example code from Microsoft's doc page on Winforms TreeView.DrawNode event:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode?view=windowsdesktop-5.0

If I comment out everything in `myTreeView_DrawNode()` and replace it with `e.DrawDefault = true;`, the CheckBoxes on the TreeView are ruined. Their rightmost pixel is overwritten.

Left side is stock TreeView with no owner drawing. Right side is as described above.

[image]

Is `.DrawDefault` hopelessly broken, or is this user error on my part?

Comment: On the right hand image, the text is also 1px higher.